# Help understanding solution of elementary number theory question?

Tags: number-theory

---

The question is:

> When expanded as a decimal, the fraction $\frac{1}{97}$ has a repetend that begins right after the decimal
> point and is 96 digits long. If the last three digits of the repetend
> are $A67$, compute the digit $A$.

---

The provided solution is:

> The repetend $x$ is a number such that $97 \cdot x = 99\cdots 9$ where
> there are 96 nines on the right side.
>
> If the hundreds digit of $x$ is $A$, then we can write
> $x = 1000k + 100A + 67$ for some integer $k$,
>
> Thus,  $99\cdots 9 - 97 \cdot (100A + 67) = 1000k$
>
> After simplifying, this implies that $99\cdots 93500 - 97 \cdot(100A)$ must be a multiple of $1000$.
>
> After dividing through by $100$, you get that $99\cdots 935 - 97A$ must have a units digit of $0$. This means that $97A$ should
> have a units digit of $5$, which occurs when $A = \boxed{5}$.

---

The part I did not understand was how they found that

> $99\cdots 9 - 97 \cdot (100A + 67) = 1000k$

given that

> $97 \cdot x = 99\cdots 9$
>
> and
>
> $x = 1000k + 100A + 67$

Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the proof is fairly simple. You have:

$$999...99 - 97(1000k + 100A + 67) = 0$$
$$999...99 - 9700A + 97 \cdot 67 = 1000\underbrace{(97k)}_{s}$$

Now it's fairly simple that RHS must be multiple of $1000$.

Here's another slightly different solution. Note that for any prime we have:

$$p \cdot \overline{a_1a_2...a_n} = 10^n - 1, \text{where } \overline{a_1a_2...a_n} \text{ is the decimal expansion of} \frac 1p$$

For our case we have $n=96$ and $p=97$.

$$p \cdot \overline{a_1a_2...a_{96}} = 10^{96} - 1$$

Working modulo $10^3$ and using that $10^{96}$ is divisible by $10^3$ we have:

$$97 \cdot \overline{a_{94}a_{95}a_{96}} \equiv -1 \pmod {10^3}$$
$$97 \cdot 100A + 97\cdot 67 \equiv 999 \pmod {10^3}$$
$$9700 A \equiv 500 \pmod {10^3}$$
$$97A \equiv 5 \pmod {10}$$

From this we can easily conclude that $A = 5$

Comment: Ah.. your solution using mod $10^3$ makes much more sense! Thanks!

Comment: @user2612743  Actally the proof you've posted uses the same logic as mine, but in my personal opinion my proof is more compact and elegant.